# Shared libraries: "Self dependency" and `g++ -shared -o <path>`?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, dynamic-linking

I use the following command to link an object file (`hello.o`) to produce a shared library (`libhello.so`):

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o build/lib/libhello.so build/obj/src/hello.o
```

I am on OS X, and `g++` actually points to `clang++` under the hood.

Then when I inspect the dependencies of `libhello.so` using

```
otool -L build/lib/libhello.so
```

the first two lines of the output is

```
build/lib/libhello.so:
    build/lib/libhello.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    ...
```

This means that any program that depends on `libhello.so` would then have to reference `libhello.so` using this **relative** path. (I have verified this using a test program linked with `libhello.so`.)

My thought is that the value of `-o` option is set as one of the dependencies of the generated `.so` file, because if I use:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o /<absolute_path>/build/lib/libhello.so build/obj/src/hello.o
```

`otool` prints:

```
build/lib/libhello.so:
    /<absolute_path>/build/lib/libhello.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    ...
```

My questions are:

1. Does `-o` have the side effect of affecting the "self dependency" of the generated shared library when used together with `-shared`?
2. Why should a shared library have a dependency pointing to itself? (I looked up a few shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib` for reference purposes, and they all have **absolute** paths to themselves as dependencies.)
3. In terms of `-o` option, what is the best practice here when producing a shared library? Using an absolute path for `-o`?

Comment: I am interested in Q2: Why should a shared library have a dependency pointing to itself? I have found this situation in my project and do not understand.